# Whats causes bug in my c++ code?

Tags: c++

I tried writing a code, which is supposed to calculate 4 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7 + 4/9 +...
but it keeps printing "3" as the answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int s=0,a,n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0 ; i<=n ; i++)
    {
        a=(4/((2*i)+1))*pow(-1,i);
        s=s+a;
    }
    cout<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what are you taking in as your value for `n`?

Comment: each number has an id from 0 to infinity . as an example if you set 2 as an "n" 's value , it will count 4 - 4/3

Comment: conio.h is from dinosaur times

Comment: haha yeah i know right . i dont even know why did i add that include

Comment: dude im just a starter lol

Comment: It would help if you'd bother to use capital letters and punctuation. _"dude im just a starter lol"_ this is not a school chatroom.

Comment: Oh alright . I'm sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3602827/560648), so your series converges really, really quickly.

Make `s` and `a` be `double`s, and replace `4` with `4.0`.

Comment: Thanks so much dude .

Comment: @Sina: I'm not your "dude". Regardless, you are welcome.

Comment: I think you'll have to transform your (2*i) into (2.0*i) too or you'll still have an integer division.

Comment: @ChrisR.: You are mistaken.